# Script for extracting information of specific pattern from a text file

Tags: python, bash, shell, pattern-matching, data-processing

Hi I am working on a project which deals with large amount of data. I have a text file of around 2 GB with key value pairs and each key has multiple values. 
I need to extract all the keys in a different file, as I need the keys for testing  a particular feature.

The format of the file is:

```
:k: k1 :v: {XYZ:{id:"k1",score:0e0,tags:null},ABC:[{XYZ:{id:"k1",score:0e0,tags:null},PQR:[{id:"ID1",score:71.85e0,tags:[{color:"DARK"},{Type:"S1"},{color:"BLACK"}]},MetaData:{RuleId:"R3",Score:66.26327129015809e0,Quality:"GOOD"}},{XYZ:{id:"k1",score:0e0,tags:null},PQR:[..(same as above format)..],MetaData:{RuleId:"R3",Score:65.8234565409752e0,Quality:"GOOD"}} ::

//same pattern repeats with different keys, and a new line
```

When I search ":k: " in the file using CTRL+F, these keys only get highlighted. SO I think this kind of pattern is no where in the file except the start of the line

Like these there are thousands of keys.

And I want all these keys (k1, k2) extracted to a separate file for testing.

There are multiple lines for :k: and want to separate (k1, k2, ..) in a separate file. How can I do this?

Python is also fine for me. I can use regular expressions in python or maybe use "sed" shell command. Please help me out here how I can use these to extract the keys.

Can someone help me in writing a shell/python script for same. I know its very trivial but I'm novice to all this kind of data processing.

Also focusing on optimizing the run time, as the data is very large.

Comment: I wouldn't call that _very trivial_. Can you provide a real example of a file (without the `...`)

Comment: I have updated the post! Let me know if anything else you want to know!

Comment: so you want to create a separate file for each "first word" (:k:) in the file? And there are multiple lines for `:k:` ? If so do you want the separate file to contain all `:k:` records, the first, the last or ??? . (your requirement is unclear). Good luck.

Comment: Yes correct. There are multiple lines for :k: and want to separate (k1, k2, ..) in a separate file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a file like

```
:k: k1 :v: {XYZ:{id:
:k2: k1 :v: {XYZ:{id:
:k: k1 :v: {XYZ:{id:
:k3: k1 :v: {XYZ:{id:
:k: k1 :v: {XYZ:{id:
```

You can easily do (in 1 pass), and with no memory restrictions

```
awk '{fName=$1; gsub(/:/,"",fName); print >> fName ; close(fName)}' inFile
```

which gives the following output

```
$ cat k
:k: k1 :v: {XYZ:{id:
:k: k1 :v: {XYZ:{id:
:k: k1 :v: {XYZ:{id:
$ cat k2
:k2: k1 :v: {XYZ:{id:
$ cat k3
:k3: k1 :v: {XYZ:{id:
```

Depending on how may keys you have, you may not need the `close(fName)`, but if you don't want to spend time testing what your limit of open files are, then this is the safe way to do the process.

IHTH